# How to show graphs on webpage using django?

Tags: html, django, numpy

I am building a webpage that takes some user input (matrix) and outputs a graph corresponding to that matrix . I am writing this code using python and numpy. So my question is I have an html page that will have input boxes to take the matrix, but how should I output my graph to the html webpage? 
I am unable to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing these data into json dict with

```
import json
data = {1: 5, 2:10}
json.dumps(data)
```

and then use JS library like D3.js to draw the graph. How draw with D3.js - https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/